# ArcGIS Server Error

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server

I'm trying to set up a hyperline in ArcMap that the URL goes to my GIS web server.  I'm getting the error message Server Error 404 - File or directory not found.  I checked to see if the file was there and it the spelling was correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: hard to tell with a generic error. If windows maybe https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011089 If you give more details might help (OS platform, version of ArcGIS/Server proxy etc.)

Answer (score 0):

AGOL is having issues. I am unable to edit any of my webmaps or applications too. Esri had a big update last night for AGOL so I suspect something went wrong. Give it a few hours.